# Please pay attention to the questions which come from a language learner

Tags: discussion

I am new to this website. I am an active user in the [English Language Learner](http://ell.stackexchange.com) website. However, sometimes I feel the need to ask questions about the style of my writings, the questions in which I know the sentence is correct or if it is not my intention from the question is just style. Several times, I was recommended to ask such questions in this site. However, whenever I do, I don't receive much help here. As it seems I don't know the mission or scope of this site.

Interestingly it happened again for this question of me [Relative clause or a new sentence. Which is better in an introductory paragraph?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/18895/relative-clause-or-a-new-sentence) . In which I asked about two styles for saying one idea. But the readers thought it is about grammar or rephrasing, while such request is nowhere in the question. I don't know how they got that feeling. Please pay more attentions to the questions which come from a language learner.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your general reader will quickly jump to the conclusion that grammar or rephrasing is the goal.

So you will have to make it really explicit what you want.
And what it is *not* about.
And please note that many people will overlook tag use entirely.

I've looked up your example and what I personally miss is a statement of what you aim to achieve with your style options listed.

Do you want to draw the reader in? Do you try to lower the barrier so people will not be put off by complex language?

I think if you state your aims advice will come easier and will be of more use.

Please be patient with us. And please keep up the good work!